Supabase storage auth with FastAPI Depends
I havee the following setup:
def get_user_token(request: Request, x_user_token: str = Header(None)):
    return x_user_token

def get_storage(token: str = Depends(get_user_token)):
    supabase.auth._headers.update({"Authorization": f"Bearer {token}"})
    return supabase.storage

class Service:
    def __init__(self, db=Depends(get_db), storage=Depends(get_storage)):
        self.db = db
        self.storage = storage

    def create_service(cls, token: str = None):
        db = get_db(token=token) if token else get_db()
        storage = get_storage(token=token) if token else get_storage()
        return cls(db=db, storage=storage)

class FileService(Service):
    def upload(self, file_name: str, file_bytes: bytes):
        self.storage.from_(config.bucket).upload(
            f"{file_name.__str__()}.csv",
            file_bytes,
        )

I also have this FastAPI endpoint:
@router.post("/endpoint")
def create_test(
    name: str,
    file_service: FileService = Depends(FileService),
):
 
    file_service.upload(
        file_name=name, file_bytes=...
    )

I'm expecting it to resolve the Depends(get_user_token). For some reason it throws error, which I believe is because the token is a Depends.
storage3.utils.StorageException: {'statusCode': 400, 'error': 'Unauthorized', 'message': 'jwt malformed'}

Is it because I'm using Depends "outside" FastAPI?

Have you tried printing out the token? That should tell you immediately if the issue is the dependency injection, or something else.

surely you can Depends in function get_user_token,
but you should get the header by Request
def get_user_token(request: Request):
    x_user_token = request.headers.get('x_user_token')
    return return 


x_user_token: str = Header(None) This will actually do the same as request.headers.get(...)
